# TypeScript accepts type of Function as type but not an explicitly typed function as a type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component:

```js
const Component = (props: Props): ReactElement => {

    const transfer = onTransfer()(props.onTransfer, props.selected);

    return (
      <div
        onClick={transfer}
```

Where the `onTransfer` function is:

```js
export const onTransfer = (): (cb: OnTransfer, selected: boolean) => void => (cb: OnTransfer, selected: boolean): void => {
    cb({
        type: selected
            ? 'select'
            : 'deselect',
    });
};
```

This implementation throws the TypeScript error:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.ts(2322)

However if I change the `onTransfer` implementation to this where I use type of `Function`:

```js
export const onTransfer = (): Function => (cb: OnTransfer, selected: boolean): void => {
    cb({
        type: selected
            ? 'select'
            : 'deselect',
    });
};
```

TypeScript does not complain.

With the latest versions of linters, using type of `Function` throws a linting error.

How to I explicitly type the function returned by the `onTransfer` function without error?

Comment: try out to replace void by `MouseEvent` in function definition?

Comment: instead of `onClick={transfer}` you could do `onClick={() => transfer()}`?

Comment: Thanks @BoussadjraBrahim this did not work

Comment: @tanmay `transfer` is not a function so I can't call it